# mysql week() function is returning one less number of actual week number

Tags: mysql

I am using week() function from mysql to determine week number from date. Problem what I am facing is that it always return one less number from actual week number. suppose today is 2013-05-15 as it is 20th week of this year but in result it is 19. Following is the query I am using.

```
 SELECT *,WEEK(date_visit) AS week_no FROM property_view_details;
```

Comment: So what's your question? Adding 1 to the result doesn't seem so difficult :)

Comment: No I do not want to add one in result :) I just want to get 20 not 19

Comment: [Read the documentation and fix your mistake](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Straight from the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week):

```
mysql> SELECT WEEK('2008-02-20',1);
    -> 8
```

You can change the behaviour of `WEEK` by setting the 2nd argument to either `0` or `1` for 0-indexed or 1-indexed results respectively.

Comment: The argument `1` will keep it zero-indexed, but change the week-counting to ISO-standard, i.e. weeks beginning on monday, first week is the one with more than three days in the new year. `2` is the equivalent of the default mode, with only the zero-indexing changed.

Answer (score 8):

Set second `week` parameter to right value.

Quoting docs:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

```
M   F.day   Range   Week 1 is the first week …
0   Sunday  0-53    with a Sunday in this year
1   Monday  0-53    with more than 3 days this year
2   Sunday  1-53    with a Sunday in this year
3   Monday  1-53    with more than 3 days this year
4   Sunday  0-53    with more than 3 days this year
5   Monday  0-53    with a Monday in this year
6   Sunday  1-53    with more than 3 days this year
7   Monday  1-53    with a Monday in this year

M = Mode
F.day = First day of week
```

Sample:

```
mysql> SELECT WEEK('2008-02-20',0);
        -> 7
mysql> SELECT WEEK('2008-02-20',1);
        -> 8
```

Answer (score 2):

The [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) should shed some light on this.

`default_week_format` is probably set to the default of `0`, which means that the week counts from zero.  Try changing it to `1`, or just adapt the query to account for the change.

Answer (score 1):

Researching the operation of the function with just a simple google turned up this: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-week-function.php

In short, you can assign a mode of operation to the function. That is, which day the week starts at, and whether it should start at 0 or 1.

For example, `SELECT WEEK(date_visit, 2)` will count with weeks starting on Sunday, and counting beginning from 1.

Best of luck.